# Facebook Microdata debugger doesn't show any preview of OpenGraph, Schema

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, microdata, nopcommerce-4.2

This is the site: https://4u.am/. It's default language is Armenaia. If i try to debug my site's url (https://4u.am/bouquet-of-roses-90-cm-3) microdata in facebook microdata debugger (https://business.facebook.com/ads/microdata/debug), it doesn't show any OpenGraph, Schema. And also shows title, description required tags are missing. **Here is facebook result:**[image]
**This site is build on nopcommerce 4.2. But i have already added these tags.
Here is rendered html.**
[image]
I am a newbie. May be I am missing something. Could anyone help?

Comment: it looks like you fixed this problem, could you add your solution as an answer? I'm in a similar situation right now. Thanks

Comment: Hi, @MaurizioPozzobon If you are using nopcommerce, Please see this:https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/boards/topic/88383/facebook-sharing-open-graph-and-foreign-languages#276201